# What are the default TransformationFunctions used in Simplify and FullSimplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, implementation-details

If I do

```
Simplify[(c^3 - s^3)^2 - (s^3 + c^3)^2, 
 TransformationFunctions -> Automatic]
```

(i.e. a verbose version of default behaviour), what transformation functions actually get applied? Similarly for FullSimplify.

The documentation says `By default FullSimplify does not use Reduce:`.  Well how would I know?  What else doesn't it use? What does it use?

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi LeafCount is the ComplexityFunction not the TransformationFunction. The question is about the latter.

Comment: +1 because I like questions about the infrastructure, but honestly I think this cannot possibly be answered.  These are the proprietary inner workings of *Mathematica* and they aren't going to be shared freely, in my estimation.

Comment: Its only a list of functions though right? No big secret I would have thought

Answer (score 9):

The documentation for [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullSimplify.html) lists the following transformations in the section *Examples → Properties & Relations* (I do not think this the list is complete): `Expand, TrigExpand, PiecewiseExpand, FunctionExpand, LogicalExpand, Factor, FactorSquareFree, TrigFactor, RootReduce, ToRadicals, Together, Apart`.

It also mentions that

> `PowerExpand` makes special assumptions on input and is not used by `FullSimplify`
>   `ComplexExpand` assumes variables to be real and is also not used by `FullSimplify`

Comment: This is potentially quite useful information: if `FullSimplify` is not giving the desired form, it makes sense to try `PowerExpand` and `ComplexExpand` manually.

Comment: I very often invoke `ComplexExpand` manually before `FullSimplify`, sometimes providing different `TargetFunctions` option to get desired result.