# What Transforming Functions does Simplify use?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, options, factorization

Edit: Turns out in my use case I should use `ComplexExpand` instead of `Simplify`. My broader question is still worth answering, but as noted in the comments it has been asked before.

I want the black box of Mathematica to tell me what it's doing with Simplify, so that I can pick and choose which parts of it to use via TransformationOptions.

Ideally AbsoluteOptions[Simplify,TransformationOptions] would do this, but that appears to not (yet?) work.

My use case: I want to simplify all terms in a 1000+ term sum without attempting to factor anything. By default Simplify "tries expanding, factoring, and doing many other transformations on expressions" (from the Simplify doc). I suspect factoring is slowing things way down, so I want to use the option TransformationOptions->{stuff besides factoring}.

Here's an example to demonstrate the slowness of Simplify (note this still runs way faster than my real use case):

```
Simplify[Conjugate[Sum[Exp[I n x], {n, 1000}]], 
  x \[Element] Reals] // Timing
(* 4.76 seconds *)
```

In sum: I want to Simplify without factoring. But if you know another way to speed up this sort of simplification, that would be nice too.

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions` often does not produce desired results.

Comment: Look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15925/1063) for some insight.

Comment: Hm unfortunately none of the functions mentioned on the FullSimplify doc page seem to make Conjugate[x]->x when x is real. I don't even know if there's a named function that's responsible for that rule.

Comment: `ComplexExpand` does what you want, and `Simplify` appears to call it.

Comment: Apply `Simplify` on each term??

Comment: @bbgodfrey You're right, `ComplexExpand` is all I needed. I guess I don't need `Simplify` now. Thanks!