# Avoid Hyperbolic functions during FullSimplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am working with a particularly complicated set of equations in continuum mechanics that I have found solutions for analytically. I am now using Mathematica to recheck my work, as well as to find simplified expressions.

To retain my ability to physically interpret the solutions in a manner that can be connected to experiment, as well as intuitive limit cases, I need to keep the solutions in exponential form. However, `FullSimplify` is rendering results that are expressed in terms of hyperbolic functions like `Sinh` and `Cosh`. How do I tell `FullSimplify` to eschew the use of hyperbolic functions?

Comment: Perhaps `TrigToExp` helps!

Comment: In addition to the advice of @Ulrich Neumann, after having done the simplifications you could replace like `expr/.{Sinh[x_]->(Exp[x]-Exp[-x])/2, Cosh[x_]->(Exp[x]+Exp[-x])/2}`. After that, you may probably need to simplify some local subexpressions. But this I cannot tell without having seen the expression.

Comment: You can take advantage of the options, `ExcludedForms`, `Trig -> False` and  `TransformationFunctions` removing `ExpToTrig` either in general, or on a particular form. [See this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27454/10397)